# Have you ever worked with Database no "Relations", no "PKs", and no "FKs", just raw data?

Tags: database, database-design

Nowadays, I'm working on a database, with no "Relations, PKs and FKs", just
raw data.
I can say that database is just set of papers.
When I asked about this, I had this; "Hide the Business".

Also, one of my friends said, this always happens in "Large systems".

In large systems, they are tyring to hide thier business through raw data.
Regarding development; relations, constraints, validation, are done in database using triggers and of course user interface.

What do you think regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this *may* have point on large databases, when you need **fast** responce on **massive** `DML` (`INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE`).

The problem is that if you rely on database's way to ensure integrity, you hardly can optimize it.

There is also thing called `SQL/PLSQL context switching` in `Oracle`: if you create an **empty** trigger on the table, it will slow down `DML` about 20 times — with the mere fact that the trigger exists.

In Oracle, when you write a `ON UPDATE` trigger and update `50,000` rows in the table, the trigger and the query in it gets called `50,000` times. Foreign keys perform better, but they may also get laggy (and you can do nothing with the underlying queries)

In this case, it's better to put the results you want to update into a temporary table, issue a `MERGE`, check integrity before and after, and apply the business rules. A single query that processes `50,000` rows works faster than a loop of `50,000` queries processing single row.

Of course, it's very hard to implement and only pays for itself when you have *really* large database and need to perform *really* massive updates on it.

In `Oracle`, in any case, `FOREING KEY` constraints perform better than tiggers implementing the same functionality.

`PRIMARY KEYS` will most likely improve performance, as a primary key implies creating the `UNIQUE INDEX` on the constrained field, and this index may be efficiently used in the queries. A `UNIQUE INDEX` is also a natural and most efficent way to enforce uniqueness.

But of course, as any index, is slows down `INSERTS` and those `UPDATES` and `DELETES` whose `WHERE` condition is not selective.

I. e. if you need to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` `1` row of `2,000,000`, then the index is your friend; if you need to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` `1,500,000` rows of `2,000,000`, the index is your enemy. It's a matter of tradeoff.

You may also see my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543274/is-it-a-best-practise-for-a-database-to-allow-apps-do-crud-operations-always-thro/543503#543503).

Comment: What I got from my friend that they depends on using triggers to ensure integrity, so we can talk about massive number of triggers in large databases, this will kill the applcation performance, so using PKs, FKs, will improve performance, right?

Comment: FK's do not improve performance at all, they are pure check constraints. PK's will most likely improve performance, as they are indexes that may speed up the queries.

Comment: But compared to triggers, FK's will most likely improve performance, if we talk of Oracle.

Comment: So, we are agreed on using PKs and FKs not none of them to design database.
So, what about "Business Hide", do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do they mean by "hiding the business". They mean security, or logic separation, or what?

Comment: They mean the business logic, if data is related to each other, you can figure the business of application?!!!

Comment: No, business logic on application side is certainly a bad idea (it it's not a basic input checking, of course). They need to create stored procedures and keep all logics there. You may read it in more detail in my previous answer by the link I gave.

Comment: It sounds like either Ahmed or his friend had a communication failure somewhere along the line, and this is not really about FK vs trigger performance, but about the human factors.

Comment: No, SquareCog, you got me wrong, I'm working on database with no relations, no PKS, or FKs.
While I told my friend about this, he told me about what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I would say sacrificing data integrity for security through obscurity is a bad trade.

Answer (score 2):

I think I came across at least two applications with databases lacking relations and FKs.

The idea is probably that it's more difficult to reverse engineer the *brillant* database schema.

The side effect is that often the applications are not so good at checking constraints themselves, leading to lot of rubbish data in the database, which in fact *does* make it more difficult to reverse engineer, as FK constraints are not enforced ;)

My view is that once it's a database, somebody else can look into it, and trying to work around this "feature" of visibility is pointless and generally Not a Good Thing, considering the drawbacks (no relations, no SPs, no triggers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Primary Keys, relations etc etc are tools for making database development easier and for making the final result faster and more efficient. I can only think of a few rare cases where not having a key/index would be a good idea.

Did your friend explain why they held this view?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can happen in financial systems.  It's the opposite of what you'd expect, you'd think that because it's finance that best practice would be applied more rigorously.  However, the converse is often true.  Many of these databases may have started out in excel.

I have seen a number of databases where they don't bother with fks or pks.  I can't say I like it, but sometimes you have to have to just live with it, or leave and go work somewhere else for less money but with more database integrity.

Perhaps this is why they need you.

Answer (score 0):

(me=MSSQL)

Deleting a row form a large table that has lots of FKs is slow.

Our APP has never been denied a Delete for a FK constraint violation on that table

I have considered dropping the FKs to improve performance.

Too chicken to have actually done it though :(

PS We would keep the FKs on the DEV / TEST systems

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this was converted from a former system that used a file based structure to hold the data. The tables in the new database are just a reflection of the individual files.